# Not understanding Biginteger prime constructor arguments

Tags: java, kotlin, biginteger

I am writing some kotlin, and would like to use the Prime constructor for BigIntegers. Because I want to generate some really big prime numbers.

The documentation for the constructor looks like this:

```
BigInteger(int bitLength, int certainty, Random rnd)
Constructs a randomly generated positive BigInteger that is probably prime, with the specified bitLength.
```

My problem is here that I find it a little unspecified what these arguments actually do.

**bitlength**
My first assumption is that this is just the amount of bits that I want the BigInt to have. This seems simple enough, but still i'm a bit in doubt about whether this means my number will use this many bits, or if it is a maximum, minimum etc.

**certainty**

This one is really mystical to me. Is this the probability that the number is prime, or the probability of that is has the beforementioned bitlength.

And on top of that, which unit do we use to denote certainty? percentages, is some probability ranking system i have never heard of?

** rnd**

I assume this is just a random generator as they come standardly in java.
But what is it used for in this context? it would be nice to be able to know why I should provide one

Hope someone can help in clearing my my confusion

The rest of the documentation is here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Perhaps [the rest of the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger-int-int-java.util.Random-) would be enlightening.

Comment: the certainty is still very very unclear.

Comment: If you set the `bitLength` argument to `b` then the resulting BigInteger's `bitLength()` method will return b. The `certainty` argument is a rather subtle mathematical point related to the underlying algorithm that is used. The algorithm cannot absolutely 100% guarantee that what it returns is prime. The details are probably beyond the scope of stackoverflow. The recommendation to use `probablePrime()` instead is a good one. To get a flavor of what the `certainty` argument is about you can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test#Accuracy)